# Matching brackets inside a regular expression does not work in bash

Tags: bash, function, arguments, glob

I defined a function that prints `yes` if its first argument contains  `a`, `b` or `c`:

```
$ func() { [[ $1 =~ [abc] ]] && echo yes; }
$ func xyz
$ func xaz
yes
$ func xbz
yes
$ func xcz
yes
```

Now I would like to detect `[`, `]` or `*` so I tried:

```
func() { [[ $1 =~ [\[\]*] ]] && echo yes; }
$ func x*z
$ func x[z
$ func x]z
yes
```

This is only seems to work for `]`. I also tried `set -f` to disable glob expansion but got same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is very well explained in  [BRE/ERE Bracketed Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) section of POSIX regex specification:

> 1. [...] The right-bracket ( `']'` ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list (after an initial circumflex ( `'^'` ), if any). Otherwise, it shall terminate the bracket expression, unless it appears in a collating symbol

Which means, your `]` needs to be present in your bracket expression at the beginning, may be after a `^`, and not anywhere later in the expression. This is a special case that applies only for `]` but not for `[` which loses its special character inside a bracket expression.

So defining

```
[[ $1 =~ [][*] ]]
```

should work as expected, because `]` at the beginning is not terminating the bracket expression. Disabling glob expansion is of no consequence here, as `*` inside a bracket expression does not have a special meaning and only treated literally.

Comment: This clarifies my question and makes the pattern cleaner (no need to escape with backslash).

Comment: I think disabling glob is needed. If there's a file in the current directory that starts with `a`, then   `func a*` will not detect the `*`.

Comment: @sergio: I meant it for the matching `*` inside the bracket expression. For arg passing yes it is needed or, the string can be passed under quotes `a*b`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution but I don't know why the old patter didn't work:

```
func() { [[ $1 =~ [\]\[*] ]] && echo yes; }
```

I changed the pattern  `[\[\]*]` to `[\]\[*]`.